Inertia in a different medium than air or vacuum
I have a problem understanding inertia in a medium more viscose than vacuum or air.
Let's consider the classical bus experiment.
The bus (a closed system) is accelerated or decelerated and a person holding the pole is respectively stumbling back, as their mass tends to remain stationary, or move forward as their mass tends to stay in motion.
Now we replace the air in the bus with another medium. Let us consider water, oil and molasses. The bus is filled to the brim, there is no air. The bus is also sealed so no medium escapes the bus.
We repeat the experiment. The bus accelerates.
I assume the mass of the person still tends to remain stationary. However the effect on the person would be milder in our medium filled bus compared to the air filled bus, correct?
It would be fantastic if someone could elaborate. If you have references I would love to read them.

You are essentially asking about damping in a system. Perhaps you can start there

There is another aspect other than viscosity/damping to consider.
The amount of damping will control the time it takes for the system to reach a dynamic equilibrium.
Immerse yourself in water in the bus and a dynamic equilibrium state will be reached faster because water is more viscous than air and the transients die away faster.
However the 'apparent' inertia of the body also needs to be considered.
What I mean by that is that the person in a bus can be considered to be a particle in a test tube of fluid inside a centrifuge.
What happens when a centrifuge is turned on?
There is a separation such that the denser particles/fluid move away from the centre of rotation, in the opposite direction to the direction of the (centripetal) acceleration, whereas the less dense particles/fluid move towards the centre of rotation, in the same direction as the acceleration.
If particles and fluid are of the same density then there is no separation.
The greater the 'average' density differential the more the effect of the acceleration will be 'felt' by the person.
The effect of a fluid with density greater than that of a person is illustrated in the video Corks in revolving water-filled jars with the person being the cork and in some accompanying notes.
